# Statement match there condition

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have question regarding condition. Question is : 
Combined length of any two sides of a triangle must be greater than the length of the third side for the segments to form a triangle. For example, 8, 6 and 12 can form a triangle because the sum of any two of the three segments is greater than the third segment.  However, 24, 5, and 15 cannot form a triangle because the sum of segments 5 and 15 are not greater than the length of segment 24.

so, my coding is like this :

```
$aa = $_GET['a'];
$bb = $_GET['b'];
$cc = $_GET['c'];
if(($aa + $bb > $cc) || ($bb + $cc > $aa) || ($aa + $cc > $bb)){
    echo"Triangle";
}

else{
    echo"Not Triangle";
}
```

it can run, but, I test those number :   8, 6 and 12 and display Triangle. for number :24, 5, and 15 it also display Triangle even the answer is Not Triangle. Can anyone tell me why? TQ

Comment: Btw, is it a homework? If so, tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Because **all** of these three conditions must be met, not **single** one. Replace

```
if(($aa + $bb > $cc) || ($bb + $cc > $aa) || ($aa + $cc > $bb)){
```

with

```
if(($aa + $bb > $cc) && ($bb + $cc > $aa) && ($aa + $cc > $bb)){
```

and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you consider that the combined length of the two shorter sides of the triangle must be greater than the length of the longest side... so if you sort the side lengths in order first so that you know which are the shortest and which is the longest, then the "if" logic is simplified

```
// Put our lengths into an array so that we can manipulate them more esily
$sideLengths = array($_GET['a'],$_GET['b'],$_GET['c']);
// Sort the array so that it's shortest to longest
sort($sideLengths);
// Test the sum of the two short sides against the longest
if (($sideLength[0] + $sideLength[1]) > $sideLength[2])
    echo"Triangle";  
} else {  
    echo"Not Triangle";  
}
```